# Problem with custom module : url redirects http to https

Tags: module, custom, routing, ssl

I have facing problem that module which I created working fine. But when I started using SSL i.e. http to https for checkout process. Front end modules which I created started to force use https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how to resolve issue of custom module frontend url is forced to https. instead of http. If you have used module creator to create module. Than you will definetly find below code in config.xml

```
<admin>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To resolve issue of redirection to https instead of http, you need to comment above code from module config.xml file Path: app/code/(codepool)/(NameSpace)/(ModuleName)/etc/config.xml OR you can add different “frontName” for  and  routers. Eg.:

```
<admin>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</admin>

<frontend>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName1]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

As per above code admin url will be http://yourdomain.com/index.php/frontName/adminhtml_moduleName/ and  frontend url will be like: http://yourdomain.com/index.php/frontName1

I hope above content is useful to you.

Comment: yes the above solution works fine for me in the same problem i had